# ListObjectsRequest is successful but PutObjectRequest returns 403 AccessDenied

Tags: java, amazon-s3, http-status-code-403

I have a ListObjectsRequest method which works as expected but also have a PutObjectRequest method which returns the following:

> com.amazonaws.shade.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: Access Denied (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDenied; Request ID: 32d91db5-b2b8-496c-9c11-546cb81453fb)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1588)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:1258)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:1030)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.doExecute(AmazonHttpClient.java:742)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.executeWithTimer(AmazonHttpClient.java:716)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:699)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutor.access$500(AmazonHttpClient.java:667)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.http.AmazonHttpClient$RequestExecutionBuilderImpl.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:649)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:513)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3639)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.invoke(AmazonS3Client.java:3586)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.services.s3.AmazonS3Client.putObject(AmazonS3Client.java:1601)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.uploadInOneChunk(UploadCallable.java:133)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadCallable.call(UploadCallable.java:125)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:143)
>     at com.amazonaws.shade.services.s3.transfer.internal.UploadMonitor.call(UploadMonitor.java:48)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

My authentication is this, where token is an IAM token extracted from a URL:

```
  String token = extractToken(path);


  propertiess = CH.updateToken(
      filesystemURI, conf, schemaProvided, token, props);
  serviceInstanceID = props.getProperty(IAM_SERVICE_INSTANCE_ID_PROPERTY);
  customToken = new CustomTokenManager(token);
  iamEndpoint = propertiess.getProperty(IAM_ENDPOINT_PROPERTY);
  SDKGlobalConfiguration.IAM_ENDPOINT = iamEndpoint;
  creds = new BasicOAuthCredentials(customToken, serviceInstanceID);

  clientConf = new ClientConfiguration();
  credProvider = new AWSStaticCredentialsProvider(creds);

  clientBuilder = AmazonS3ClientBuilder.standard()
      .withClientConfiguration(clientConf)
      .withPathStyleAccessEnabled(true)
      .withCredentials(credProvider);

  if (serviceUrl != null && !serviceUrl.equals(amazonDefaultEndpoint)) {

    EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration(serviceUrl,
        Regions.DEFAULT_REGION.getName());
    clientBuilder.withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration);

  } else {

          clientBuilder.withRegion(Regions.DEFAULT_REGION);
  }

  mClient = clientBuilder.build();
}
```

Does anybody know why one would succeed and the other throws a 403? As far as I can tell, my endpoint, bucket, object and token are all correct.

Update:
After further investigation, it actually seems to be the upload that is failing:

```
    PutObjectRequest putObjectRequest = new PutObjectRequest(mBucket, objName, im, om);
    Upload upload = transfers.upload(putObjectRequest);
    upload.waitForUploadResult();
```

I get the error fron the waitForUploadResult().

Also, I'm trying to upload to Bluemix Cloud Object Stroage.

Here's the roles on my [service instance](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GHdIO.png).

Comment: What about the bucket and/or user policy (which controls permissions)?  Each permission is separate.

Comment: I checked that also but can't see anything that should cause an issue.

Comment: Show your policy?

Comment: Added what I think you're looking for to the post.

Comment: *"Also, I'm trying to upload to Bluemix Cloud Object Storage."*  oh and by the way, I'm not using Amazon S3...  needs to be mentioned more prominently. You should add a tag to indicate such.  I'm quite familiar with the low-level details of S3 but have nothing to go on related to Bluemix.